# Why do we use singular verb with third person after gerund?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Why do we use singular verb in sentences like this:

Just sitting here and watching the world go by. (not goes)

Just sitting here and watching paint dry. (not dries)

The world goes, doesn't it?

Comment: I watch the sun *set*.  I hear the bird *sing*.  I felt the shirt *rip*. Verbs of perception have object complements with bare infinitive.

Comment: @TRomano But *For weeks I watched him drowning himself in a bottle.* (I just wanted to add another possibility.)

Comment: @Damkerng T. Right. We can say *I saw him painting* and *I saw him paint*.  The former I understand to mean "I saw that he was painting" and the latter to mean "I saw his painting technique".

Comment: @TRomano: I don't think either OP's examples or yours feature *gerunds*, but I agree ***go by, dry, paint*** are all bare infinitives. Your semantic distinction doesn't seem to me to be inherent in the choice of verb form - it's just that *because* there are two alternatives, we're tempted to assign them different meanings. Personally, if I *had* to "invent" a distinction between *"I heard you laughing"* and *"I heard you laugh"* I'd probably say the latter implied I only heard you come out with one short burst of laughter, which seems almost "opposite" to your *paint* difference.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I wouldn't argue for any *grammatical* difference, but for one based on usage. If I wanted to say that I could hear the faint sound of a female vocalist off in the distance, I'd say *I could hear her singing off in the distance* but if I wanted to say that I'd been to a concert at which June Tabor  performed, I'd say "I've heard June Tabor sing".

Comment: @TRomano: I think for any given verb+context there's often a "natural, preferred" choice between progressive/continuous and unmarked infinitive, so we just seek out *any* credible alternative meaning for the less common form. Apropos nothing, if I respond with *"Snap! I've heard her **singing** too!"* it seems something of an open question whether that one really *is* a gerund as opposed to progressive tense. It's not grammatically fixed, but arguably depends on what I as the speaker/writer had in mind at time of utterance/writing. (Or perhaps better, what *you* perceive at time of reading! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the world and the paint aren't the subjects of the sentences, which means there's not a fixed point in time when the world goes or the paint dries. Consider this sentence:

> The clock ticks

The clock is the subject, so we conjugate "to tick" into the present simple. However if the clock is not the subject, then the verb "to tick" doesn't get conjugated:

> Electricity makes the clock tick

This is because the ticking doesn't just happen in the present tense, the electricity gives the clock the ability **to tick**, which is why we use the infinitive.

Comment: OK, I think I got it. So, in the same manner: I was watching the river flow. I will be watching the river flow. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct!